# best way to parallelize calculations on time series data in matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, mathematical-optimization

I have a linux cluster with Matlab & PCT installed (128 workers with Torque Manager), and I am looking for a good way to parallelize my calculations.

I have a time-series Trajectory data (100k x 2) matrix. I perform maximum likelihood (ML) calculations that involve  matrix diagonalization, exponentiation & multiplications, which is running fast for smaller matrices. I divide the Trajectory data into small chunks and perform the calculations on many workers (coarse parallelization) and don't have any problems here as it works fine (gets done in ~30s)

But the calculations also depend on a number of parameters that I need to vary & test the effect on ML. (something akin to parameter sweep).

When I try to do this using a loop, the calculations becomes progressively very slow, for some reason I am unable to figure out.

```
%%%%%%% Pseudo- Code Example:

% a [100000x2], timeseries data
load trajectoryData 

% p1,p2,p3,p4 are parameters 
% but i want to do this over a multiple values fp3 & fp4 ;
paramsMat = [p1Vect; p2Vect;p3Vect ;p4Vect];
matlabpool start 128

[ML] = objfun([p1 p2 p3 p4],trajectoryData) % runs fast ~ <30s 

%% NOTE: this runs progressively slow 
for i = 1:length(paramsMat)

     currentparams = paramsMat(i,:);
     [ML] = objfun(currentparams,trajectoryData)
end
matlabpool close
```

The objFunc function is as follows:

```
% objFunc.m
[ML] = objFunc(Params, trajectoryData) 

% b = 2 always
[a b] = size(trajectoryData) ;

% split into fragments of 1000 points  (or any other way)
fragsMat = reshape(trajectoryData,1000, a*2/1000) ;

% simple parallelization. do the calculation on small chunks
parfor ix = 1: numFragments
   % do heavy calculations
   costVal(ix) = costValFrag; 
end

% just an example; 
ML = sum(costVal) ; 

%%%%%%
```

Just a single calculation oddly takes ~30s (using the full cluster) but within the for loop, for some weird reason there is damping of speed & even within the 100th calculation, it becomes very slow. The workers are using only 10-20% of CPU.

If you have any suggestions including alternative parallelization suggestions it would be of immense help.

Comment: Maybe this is a problem with memory allocation and not the parallelisation? Do you have any arrays in your code that grow with every cycle?

Comment: Not in the core calculation(objFunc). I store the results in a cell array that grows every time. But, i preallocate it.

Comment: Very odd, now am running the calculation with a 3000 parameters set (3000 x 4 matrix). In the beginning, the cpu utilization is around 60-70% in all the workers and even by the time of 100th iteration, it has dropped to 25% cpu usage. basically calling the same objFun with different parameters. should be trivial but apparently there is something weird. any tests that I could do ?

Answer (score 1):

If I read this correctly, each parameter set is completely independent of all the others, and you have more parameter sets than you do workers.

The simple solution is to use a batch job instead of parfor.

```
job_manager = findresource( ... look up the args that fit your cluster ... )
job = createJob(job_manager);
for i = 1:num_param_sets
    t = createTask(job, @your_function, 0, {your params});
end
submit(job);
```

This way you avoid any communications overhead you have from the parfor of the inner function, and you keep your matlabs separate. You can even tell it to automatically restart the workers between tasks (I think), as one of the job parameters.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `numFragments`? If this is not always larger than your number of workers, then you will see things slowing down.

I would suggest trying to make your outer `for` loop be the `parfor`. It's generally better to apply the parallelism at the outermost level.

Comment: numFragments is always > numWorkers; Can't make the outer loop to be parfor because the intensive calculations has to be done on the time trajectory fragments within the objFunction

Comment: by how much does numFragments exceed numWorkers?

Comment: am splitting the trajectories (~130-150,000) into pieces of 1000.so numFragments would be 130~150. so it's on the same order more or less as my numWorkers is ~128.

Comment: and I also have trajectories that could be much longer (800,000-1million), so numFragments will be > numWorkers.

Comment: Even a suggestion of a good test would help! Right now am trying a work around of restarting the matlabpool after 25-50 calculations. It helps but is a very unclean solution.

Comment: I would suggest keeping numTargets much greater than numWorkers, otherwise the tail of the calculation will use far fewer workers. In the worst case of numTargets = (numWorkers+1), then your computation will take twice as long as you might expect.

Comment: Thanks Edric. It seems to be so in this case (numTargets > numWorkers), still am observing a progressive slow down. Is there any standard performance tests for distributed calculations like this ? I thought this is trivially parallelizable and that it won't have much issues, but am indeed facing weird problems.